# Split Power supply in voltage and gnd?

Tags: arduino-uno, power, electronics, electricity

I am new to electronics and arduino in general. I need to split a power supply in gnd and voltage. Basically, the power supply has one single wire (with the voltage and the gnd passing through it i think), and I need them to be separated. Sorry if this is a noob question, but I am really new to this whole thing.

Comment: Voltage is also called "electric potential DIFFERENCE". There is no such thing as "a wire with a voltage of 5V", but always "a 5V voltage with respect to this ground". Carrying away just the 5V wire is meaningless. And you can't carry both Vcc and ground on the same wire. So.. If you have one wire, there are TWO conductors. If they are coaxial (RGx cables), two wires or coated wires (like in cheap headphones), it doesn't matter. But.. You already have two wires. If you are not sure, post a photo and we'll try to figure out what are the two wires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a image of this? Logically, and as far as I know, One wire will not carry both GND and Positive.

Are you talking of a DC jack kind of thing?

BTW, I'm starting out here too!

Comment: It's exactly a DC jack that i needed! Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

If the cable of the power supply contains voltage and gnd, it's two cables, with a layer between them.

[image]

On the inside they look much like coaxial cables, so if you softly cut the outer shell(A) you maye see a mesh of blank wires(B,C,D), they're gnd in most cases.
There also is an inner wire(C) which you have to cut softly, too.
That's the voltage carrying wire(D), in most cases. (If it's approx. less than 10 Volts, check with a LED.)